# Simplest way to drive a Nema 17? Without Breadboard and all that gobbledygook

Tags: stepper-motor, stepper-driver

I would like to setup a nema 17 with a belt... is there like some chip board / module with everything built in where I can plug in the stepper and program it to go forward and back without all the crazy breadboard wires and tons of gobbledygook... everytime I look up how to hookup a Stepper motor its got all this crazy wires and everything... you think a company would have made like an easy module to program without that breadboard... will it work on one of them small Aurdionos.. I got me a bunch of them laying around

Comment: what component is gobbledygook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to google "stepper motor arduino shield". That add-on item plugs into (onto) an arduino without crazy wires. You will need wires to power the arduino, to power the motor controller (perhaps shared with the arduino), and of course the wires of the motor itself. Those are necessary, not crazy. Raspberry Pis accept similar add-on items, called "hats".